# Jenkins : How to run a shell script at the exact end of a pipeline

Tags: python, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline which run a job on a remote agent (kubernetes as cloud agent), but at the end of the job i want to run a python script on the master Jenkins.
I've tried to use the POST section, but it seems in the POST section it's still executing on the 1st remote agent and not on the master as i would like.

Any suggestion to ensure the proprer execution on the good host ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify "agent none" at beginning of pipeline script and set "remote_agent" at each stage level.

See pipeline script below:

```
    pipeline {
        agent none
        stages {
            stage('stage1') {
                agent {
                    label 'remote_agent1'
                    }
                 steps {
                    script {
                        #do_something // this code will run on remote_agent1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            always {
                script {
                    #do_something //this code will run on master
                }
            }
        }    
    }
```